# Remove specific string base on some list in python

Tags: python, string, replace

I Have string, from some xml element:

```
source = "<![CDATA[<p><span stylefontfamily times new romantimesserif fontsize large>Is important ?</span></p>]]
```

"

I wanna Remove specified string base on this list:

`mustDelWord=["<p>","</p>","<span stylefontfamily times new romantimesserif fontsize large>","</span>"]`

So, the expected output is:

```
<![CDATA[Is important ?]]>
```

So far code is :

```
mustDelWord=["<p>","</p>","<span stylefontfamily times new romantimesserif fontsize large>","</span>"]  

for i in mustDelWord:
        source = source.replace(mustDelWord[i],"")
print source
```

But occur this error:

```
source = source.replace(mustDelWord[i],"")
```

TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str

Thanks.

Comment: These are the kind of silly mistakes that can easily be solved if you just try checking the code yourself. In this case, a simple `print i` would have told you exactly what the problem was. Conversely, having read a basic introduction to Python and learned how for loops in python work, would also have prevented you from needing to come here and waste everyone's time.

Comment: OOT. Sure. Your head shot it's true. It's silly anyway. But thanks a lot for your advice. Sorry if i bother you. Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change the line to:

```
source = source.replace(i,"")
```

This is because the loop `for i in mustDelWord` already iterates over the elements in the list, *not* the indices in that list, so you don't have to do `mustDelWord[i]`.